# Adjust new features in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

The executable code below is generating clusters and showing on the maps made by the leaflet (I inserted a figure of the visual structure of my shiny below). However, I would like help with my Filter2, which was just to show the properties inserted in the cluster selected in Filter1. However, for example, considering sliderInput as 3. Cluster 1 has 3 properties, but is showing the selection of 7 properties (Error below). Therefore, I would like you to help me adjust my Filter2 so that I can show only the property on the map, from a cluster selected in Filter1.

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(rdist)
library(geosphere)
library(shinythemes)
library(leaflet)

function.cl<-function(df,k,Filter1,Filter2){

  #database df
  df<-structure(list(Properties = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7), 
                     Latitude = c(-23.8, -23.8, -23.9, -23.9, -23.9,-23.4,-23.5), 
                     Longitude = c(-49.6, -49.3, -49.4, -49.8, -49.6,-49.4,-49.2), 
                     Waste = c(526, 350, 526, 469, 285, 433, 456)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))


  #clusters
  coordinates<-df[c("Latitude","Longitude")]
  d<-as.dist(distm(coordinates[,2:1]))
  fit.average<-hclust(d,method="average") 
  clusters<-cutree(fit.average, k) 
  nclusters<-matrix(table(clusters))  
  df$cluster <- clusters 

  #specific cluster and specific propertie
  df1<-df[c("Latitude","Longitude")]
  df1$cluster<-as.factor(clusters)
  df_spec_clust <- df1[df1$cluster == Filter1,]
  df_spec_prop<-df1[df1$Properties==Filter2,]

  #Table to join df and df1
  data_table <- Reduce(merge, list(df, df1))

  #Color and Icon for map
  ai_colors <-c("red","gray","blue","orange","green","beige","darkgreen","lightgreen", "lightred", "darkblue","lightblue",
                "purple","darkpurple","pink", "cadetblue","white","darkred", "lightgray","black")
  clust_colors <- ai_colors[df$cluster]
  icons <- awesomeIcons(
    icon = 'ios-close',
    iconColor = 'black',
    library = 'ion',
    markerColor =  clust_colors)

  leafIcons <- icons(
    iconUrl = ifelse(df1$Properties,
                     "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/542/542461.svg"
    ),
    iconWidth = 45, iconHeight = 40,
    iconAnchorX = 25, iconAnchorY = 12)
   html_legend <- "<img src='https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/542/542461.svg'>"

  # Map for all clusters:
  m1<-leaflet(df1) %>% addTiles() %>%
    addMarkers(~Longitude, ~Latitude, icon = leafIcons) %>%
    addAwesomeMarkers(lat=~df$Latitude, lng = ~df$Longitude, icon=icons, label=~as.character(df$cluster)) %>% 
    addLegend( position = "topright", title="Cluster", colors = ai_colors[1:max(df$cluster)],labels = unique(df$cluster))
  plot1<-m1

  # Map for specific cluster and propertie
  m2<-leaflet(df_spec_clust) %>% addTiles() %>%
    addMarkers(~Longitude, ~Latitude, icon = leafIcons) %>%
    addAwesomeMarkers(lat=~df_spec_prop$Latitude, lng = ~df_spec_prop$Longitude, icon=icons, label=~as.character(df$cluster)) 
    plot2<-m2


  return(list(
    "Plot1" = plot1,
    "Plot2" = plot2,
    "Data" = data_table
  ))
}

ui <- bootstrapPage(
  navbarPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"), collapsible = TRUE,
             "Cl", 
             tabPanel("Solution",
                      sidebarLayout(
                        sidebarPanel(
                          tags$b(h3("Choose the cluster number?")),
                          sliderInput("Slider", h5(""),
                                      min = 2, max = 5, value = 3),
                        ),
                        mainPanel(
                          tabsetPanel(      
                            tabPanel("Solution", (leafletOutput("Leaf1",width = "95%", height = "600")))))

                      ))),
  tabPanel("",
           sidebarLayout(
             sidebarPanel(
               selectInput("Filter1", label = h4("Select just one cluster to show"),""),
               selectInput("Filter2",label=h4("Select the cluster property designated above"),""),
             ),
             mainPanel(
               tabsetPanel(
                 tabPanel("Map", (leafletOutput("Leaf2",width = "95%", height = "600")))))
           )))

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  Modelcl<-reactive({
    function.cl(df,input$Slider,input$Filter1,input$Filter2)
  })

  output$Leaf1 <- renderLeaflet({
    Modelcl()[[1]]
  })

   output$Leaf2 <- renderLeaflet({
     Modelcl()[[2]]
   })

  observeEvent(input$Slider, {
    abc <- req(Modelcl()$Data)
    updateSelectInput(session,'Filter1',
                      choices=sort(unique(abc$cluster)))
  }) 

   observeEvent(input$Filter1, {
     abc <- req(Modelcl()$Data)
      updateSelectInput(session,'Filter2',
                       choices=sort(unique(abc$Properties)))
    }) 

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

#### Visual structure of my shiny

[image]

#### Error

[image]

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the data_table returned by the function isn't filtered.

You can filter it in the `observeEvent`:

```
abc <- req(Modelcl()$Data) %>% filter(cluster == as.numeric(input$Filter1))
```

If so you can simplify using an `observe`:

```
observe({
    abc <- req(Modelcl()$Data) %>% filter(cluster == as.numeric(input$Filter1))
    updateSelectInput(session,'Filter2',
                      choices=sort(unique(abc$Properties)))
})
```

Comment: Thanks friend, it worked. Just another question would you know how do I generate this second map only when an option from Filter1 and an option from Filter2 are selected?

Comment: In the UI part, you can replace `leafletOutput("Leaf2",width = "95%", height = "600")` by `uiOutput("myOptionalMap")` and add in the server part `output$myOptionalMap <- renderUI({ if(input$Filter1) leafletOutput("Leaf2",width = "95%", height = "600") })`

Comment: I tried the way you described friend, but it gave error. I think it's because server where you said: ```output$myOptionalMap <- renderUI({ if(input$Filter1) leafletOutput("Leaf2",width = "95%", height = "600") })```, how will "Leaf2" be read, if I had to substitute in my ui for ```uiOutput ("myOptionalMap")```. Again, thanks!

Comment: Please ask in a new question and post the link here :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61741392/shiny-new-adjustments