# How to Link selected cluster in shiny app

Tags: r, google-maps, shiny, googleway

First, I'll present an example below for you to see how it works. The code below generates the route between two coordinates.

```
library(googleway)

set_key( "API KEY")


#databases
  df<-structure(list(Properties = c(1,2), 
                     Latitude = c(-24.930473, -24.95575), 
                     Longitude = c(-49.994889, -49.990162), 
                     cluster = c(1,2)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
  
  df1<-structure(list(Properties = c(3,4),Latitude = c(-24.924361,-24.95575), 
                       Longitude = c(-50.004343, -50.007371), 
                       cluster = c(1,2)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))

 #Table to join df and df1
  data_table <- rbind(df,df1)
  data_table<-data_table[c(2:3)]

  df2<-google_directions(origin = data_table[1,], destination = data_table[3,], 
                        mode = "driving") #I specified properties 1 and 3 which are from cluster 1
  
  df_routes <- data.frame(polyline = direction_polyline(df2))
  
  
  m1<-google_map() %>%
    add_polylines(data = df_routes, polyline = "polyline")
```

[image]

Now, I'm trying to do this in Shiny, but without specifying the coordinates of the properties like I did in the example above. In this sense, I created a `selecInput` to select which cluster I want to see the route. How to adjust this in this code below?

This question can help: [Adjust new features in shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61736471/adjust-new-features-in-shiny)

```
library(shiny)
library(rdist)
library(geosphere)
library(shinythemes)
library(googleway)


set_key( "API KEY")



function.cl<-function(df,df1,k,Filter1){
  
  #database df
  df<-structure(list(Properties = c(1,2), 
                     Latitude = c(-24.930473, -24.95575), 
                     Longitude = c(-49.994889, -49.990162), 
                     cluster = c(1,2)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
  
  df1<-structure(list(Properties = c(3,4),Latitude = c(-24.924361,-24.95575), 
                      Longitude = c(-50.004343, -50.007371), 
                      cluster = c(1,2)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
  
  #Table to join df and df1
  data_table <- rbind(df,df1)
  data_table1<-data_table[c(2:3)]
  
  #Generate the map with routes
  
  df2<-google_directions(origin = data_table1[1,], destination = data_table1[3,], 
                         mode = "driving")
  
  df_routes <- data.frame(polyline = direction_polyline(df2))
  
  
  m1<-google_map() %>%
    add_polylines(data = df_routes, polyline = "polyline")
  
  plot1<-m1 
  
  return(list(
    "Plot1" = plot1,
    "Data" = data_table
  ))
}

ui <- bootstrapPage(
  
  navbarPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"), collapsible = TRUE,
             "Cl", 
             tabPanel("Map of all clusters",
                      sidebarLayout(
                        sidebarPanel(
                          tags$b(h3("Choose the cluster number?")),
                          sliderInput("Slider", h5(""),
                                      min = 2, max = 2, value = 2),
                          selectInput("Filter1", label = h4("Select just one cluster to show"),""),
                        ),
                        
                        mainPanel(
                          tabsetPanel(      
                            tabPanel("Solution", (google_mapOutput("G2",width = "95%", height = "600")))))
                        
                      ))))


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  Modelcl<-reactive({
    function.cl(df,df1,input$Slider,input$Filter1)
  })

    output$G2 <- renderGoogle_map({
    Modelcl()[[1]]
  })
  
  
  observeEvent(input$Slider, {
    abc <- req(Modelcl()$Data)
    updateSelectInput(session,'Filter1',
                      choices=sort(unique(abc$cluster)))
  }) 
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `k` represents the cluster number that you are targeting, and `cluster` is a column in your dataset (I don't understand why you have `df` and `df1`, and then row bind them together), then you can simply do something like this to limit the input to the `google_directions()` call to only be the rows that correspond to cluster `k`

```
data_table1<-data_table[data_table$cluster==k,c(2:3)]
```

Then, in the call to `google_directions()`, you would do this (notice that I'm now calling row 1 and row 2 (instead of row 1 and row 3 in your example), because the filtering on `data_table$cluster==k` above has ensured that data_table1 has only the two rows associated with cluster `k`

```
df2<-google_directions(
  origin = data_table1[1,],
  destination = data_table1[2,],
  mode = "driving")
```

Finally, I'm not sure you want to return all of `data_table`. Perhaps you adjust so that it returns only `data_table1` (i.e. the subset wih your cluster of interest)?:

```
return(list(
  "Plot1" = plot1,
  "Data" = data_table1
))
```

Comment: Thanks for reply @langtang. It just helps me to understand: when I select cluster 1 in `selectInput `a graph appears, when I select cluster 2, shouldn't a different graph appear? because is other coordinates.

Comment: well, are you selecting two different clusters when you move the slider? The slider currently only takes 1 possible value -- min and max are the same!!!

Comment: Did that solve it @Antonio, or was there something missing in my code?

Comment: I believe you are right. Let me check something first.

Comment: That's right! I'll have one more question on this, but it's better to ask a different question. As soon as I do, I'll insert the link here, in case you can look. Thank you again @langtang