# Adjust to generate correct maps from selecInput

Tags: r, google-maps, shiny, googleway

First of all, I will make a brief example for you to understand the idea.

```
library(googleway)

set_key( "API KEY")


df<-structure(list(Properties = c(1,2,3,4), 
                     Latitude = c(-24.930473, -24.95575,-24.990473, -24.99575), 
                     Longitude = c(-49.994889, -49.990162,-49.999889, -49.999162), 
                     cluster = c(1,2,1,2)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
  
  df1<-structure(list(Latitude = c(-24.924361,-24.95575), 
                      Longitude = c(-50.004343, -50.007371), 
                      cluster = c(1,2)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
  
 # considering `Filter1= 1`, that is, cluster 1 that I want to see, and `Filter2= 3`, that is property number 3, so:

Filter1=1

Filter2=3

  data_table1<-df1[df1$cluster==Filter1,c(1:2)]
  data_table2<-df[df$Properties==Filter2,c(2:3)]
  
 
   #Generate the map with routes
  
  df2<-google_directions(origin = data_table1, destination = data_table2, 
                         mode = "driving")
  
  df_routes <- data.frame(polyline = direction_polyline(df2))
  
  
  m1<-google_map() %>%
    add_polylines(data = df_routes, polyline = "polyline")
```

[image]

Now, my idea is to use shiny. In this sense, I created two `selecInput`, the first corresponds to `Filter 1` (which cluster do you want to see) and the other to `Filter 2` (which property do you want to see). Choosing these two pieces of information generates the route as I did in the example above. However, I am not able to fix this problem in shiny.

This question is very similar and might help: [How to Link selected cluster in shiny app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71506509/how-to-link-selected-cluster-in-shiny-app) However, it has some differences, for example I have inserted one more filter .

```
library(shiny)
library(rdist)
library(geosphere)
library(shinythemes)
library(googleway)


set_key( "API KEY")



function.cl<-function(df,df1,k,Filter1){
  
  #database df
  df<-structure(list(Properties = c(1,2,3,4), 
                     Latitude = c(-24.930473, -24.95575,-24.990473, -24.99575), 
                     Longitude = c(-49.994889, -49.990162,-49.999889, -49.999162), 
                     cluster = c(1,2,1,2)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
  
  df1<-structure(list(Latitude = c(-24.924361,-24.95575), 
                      Longitude = c(-50.004343, -50.007371), 
                      cluster = c(1,2)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
  

  data_table1<-df1[df1$cluster==Filter1,c(1:2)]
  data_table2<-df[df$Properties==Filter2,c(2:3)]
  
 
   #Generate the map with routes
  
  df2<-google_directions(origin = data_table1, destination = data_table1, 
                         mode = "driving")
  
  df_routes <- data.frame(polyline = direction_polyline(df2))
  
  
  m1<-google_map() %>%
    add_polylines(data = df_routes, polyline = "polyline")
  
  plot1<-m1 
  
  return(list(
    "Plot1" = plot1,
    "Data" = df
  ))
}

ui <- bootstrapPage(
  
  navbarPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"), collapsible = TRUE,
             "Cl", 
             tabPanel("Map of all clusters",
                      sidebarLayout(
                        sidebarPanel(
                          tags$b(h3("Choose the cluster number?")),
                          sliderInput("Slider", h5(""),
                                      min = 2, max = 2, value = 2),
                          selectInput("Filter1", label = h4("Select just one cluster to show"),""),
                          selectInput("Filter2", label = h4("Select the propertie"),""),
                        ),
                        
                        mainPanel(
                          tabsetPanel(      
                            tabPanel("Solution", (google_mapOutput("G2",width = "95%", height = "600")))))
                        
                      ))))


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  Modelcl<-reactive({
    function.cl(df,df1,input$Slider,input$Filter1)
  })
  
  output$G2 <- renderGoogle_map({
    Modelcl()[[1]]
  })
  
  
  observeEvent(input$Slider, {
    abc <- req(Modelcl()$Data)
    updateSelectInput(session,'Filter1',
                      choices=sort(unique(abc$cluster)))
  }) 
  
  observeEvent(c(input$Filter1 ),{
    abc <- req(Modelcl()$Data) %>% filter(cluster == as.numeric(input$Filter1))   
    updateSelectInput(session,'Filter2',
                      choices = unique(abc$Propertie))
    
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your shiny example as three inputs:

1. `Slider`, which gets passed to `k` in the function signature
2. `Filter1`, which appears to be the same as `k` (i.e. choosing a cluster), and currently gets passed to `Filter1` in the function signature
3. `Filter2`, which is for selecting the Property, but never gets passed to the function.

I think what you want to do is include only `Slider` and `Filter2` (or `Filter1` and `Filter2`).

Then change the `Modelcl` to

```
  Modelcl<-reactive({
    function.cl(df,df1,input$Slider,input$Filter2)
  })
```

Then, in your actual function, rename your inputs in the signature so that they are better aligned with what you are passing in. I suggest something like this:

```
function.cl<-function(df,df1,cluster,property){
```

Then, you can

```
data_table1<-df1[df1$cluster==cluster,c(1:2)]
data_table2<-df[df$Properties==property,c(2:3)]
```

Finally, notice that you have an error in your call to `google_directions()`. you need to make sure that the `origin` and `destination` parameters are different.  currently, they are both set to `data_table1`

Here is an example, with the changes made:

```
library(shiny)
library(rdist)
library(geosphere)
library(shinythemes)
library(googleway)


function.cl<-function(df,df1,cluster,property){
  

  #database df
  df<-structure(list(Properties = c(1,2,3,4), 
                     Latitude = c(-24.930473, -24.95575,-24.990473, -24.99575), 
                     Longitude = c(-49.994889, -49.990162,-49.999889, -49.999162), 
                     cluster = c(1,2,1,2)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
  
  df1<-structure(list(Latitude = c(-24.924361,-24.95575), 
                      Longitude = c(-50.004343, -50.007371), 
                      cluster = c(1,2)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
  
  
  data_table1<-df1[df1$cluster==cluster,c(1:2)]
  data_table2<-df[df$Properties==property,c(2:3)]
  

  #Generate the map with routes
  
  df2<-google_directions(origin = data_table1, destination = data_table2, 
                         mode = "driving")
  
  df_routes <- data.frame(polyline = direction_polyline(df2))
  
  
  m1<-google_map() %>%
    add_polylines(data = df_routes, polyline = "polyline")
  
  plot1<-m1 
  
  return(list(
    "Plot1" = plot1,
    "Data" = df
  ))
}

ui <- bootstrapPage(
  
  navbarPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"), collapsible = TRUE,
             "Cl", 
             tabPanel("Map of all clusters",
                      sidebarLayout(
                        sidebarPanel(
                          tags$b(h3("Choose the cluster number?")),
                          sliderInput("Slider", h5(""),
                                      min = 1, max = 2, value = 1,step = 1),
                          selectInput("Filter2", label = h4("Select the properties"),choices =c(1,2,3,4)),
                        ),
                        
                        mainPanel(
                          tabsetPanel(      
                            tabPanel("Solution", (google_mapOutput("G2",width = "95%", height = "600")))))
                        
                      ))))


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  Modelcl<-reactive({
    function.cl(df,df1,input$Slider,input$Filter2)
  })
  
  output$G2 <- renderGoogle_map({
    Modelcl()[[1]]
  })
  
  
  observeEvent(input$Slider, {
    abc <- req(Modelcl()$Data)
    updateSelectInput(session,'Filter1',
                      choices=sort(unique(abc$cluster)))
  }) 
  
  # observeEvent(c(input$Filter1 ),{
  #   abc <- req(Modelcl()$Data) %>% filter(cluster == as.numeric(input$Filter1))   
  #   updateSelectInput(session,'Filter2',
  #                     choices = unique(abc$Propertie))
  #   
  # })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However, it is not generating the routes properly. The `selectInput` options are ok, but when I chose, for example, cluster 1 and property 3, I would have to route between the coordinates of property 3 that is in the `df` dataset with the coordinate of cluster 1 that is in `df1`, as was done in the first example, but this is not happening. In this case, I would have to generate a graph equal to the one I inserted in the first example.

Comment: you'll have to explain what your problem is. the approach/code i have is correct

Comment: you have to be careful with your coding. notice that your origin and destination sources are the same in the call to `google_directions()`

Comment: Thanks for your comments @langtang. I adjusted the same as your code and also insert `destination = data_table2`, in `google_directions`, it was supposed to work, however it didn't in shiny code. Strange! If I do `cluster=1` and `property = 3` and then `data_table1<-df1[df1$cluster==cluster,c(1:2)]` I have the coordinates properly of cluster 1 and if I do `data_table2< -df[df$Properties==property,c(2:3)]`, I have the coordinates of property 3 properly. After that, I can properly generate the graph of the route. But on shiny, it doesn't work, do you know why?

Comment: You probably are NOT passing cluster and property to the function. Do some debugging. A simple approach is to have the function (add as first line of the function) print property and cluster so you can see exactly what it is receiving from the shiny inputs. Also your shiny app example doesn’t provide any values in the Filter1 input choices

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I had to leave. I understand what you want me to do, buti don't know how to do what you said in the code, can you help me?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243126/discussion-between-langtang-and-antonio).

Comment: langtang, I asked a question similar to this one, and a question we were chatting about. I detailed it to make it understandable. If you can take a look, I'd appreciate it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71608236/problems-generating-route-between-two-coordinates-in-a-shiny-app